# UISearchBar Disabling Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

I have implemented my search bar into my app and everything works great. The only issue I ma having is say I search for a state and I type in California, I then press California in the results and it takes me to the next view. Once I get to that view I want to go back to my last view. When I press back it takes me to my state view where I originally did the search, but the search bar is still enabled and has the text California still in it with the result. I have tried the following line of code:

```
_searchBar.text = nil;
```

This line does clear the text, but still has the keyboard showing and the search bar still enabled. What I would like is for the table view to go back to normal when I press back. Is there a method for that? I have looked and the line I posted above is closest thing I have found.

**RootTableViewController.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RootTableViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *objects;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *results;

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;

@end
```

**RootTableViewController.m:**

```
#import "RootTableViewController.h"
#import "SecondTableViewController.h"

@interface RootTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation RootTableViewController
{
NSArray *states;
}

- (NSMutableArray*)objects;
{
if (!_objects)
{
    _objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

return _objects;
}

- (NSMutableArray*)results;
{
if (!_results)
{
    _results = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

return _results;
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

states = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Alabama", @"Georgia", @"Tennessee", @"Colorado", nil];

[self.objects addObjectsFromArray:states];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (void)searchThroughData
{
self.results = nil;

NSPredicate *resultsPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains [search] %@", self.searchBar.text];

self.results = [[self.objects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultsPredicate] mutableCopy];
}

- (void) searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
[self searchThroughData];
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if (tableView == self.tableView)
{
    return self.objects.count;
}

else
{
    [self searchThroughData];
    return self.results.count;
}
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//table identifier
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"StateCell";

//creating a cell
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (!cell)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyleDefault) reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}

if (tableView == self.tableView)
{
    cell.textLabel.text = self.objects[indexPath.row];
}

else
{
    cell.textLabel.text = self.results[indexPath.row];
}

return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (self.searchDisplayController.isActive)
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showStateDetail" sender:self];
}
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

if (self.searchBar.text.length) 
{
     [self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:NO];
}
}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
//push segue identifier 'showArrayDetail'
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showStateDetail"])
{
    //row that we clicked on
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

    //'SecondTableVieController' object is created
    SecondTableViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

    //sets 'stateName' to what row you pick
    destViewController.stateName = [states objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //sets title to 'stateName' you picked
    destViewController.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Areas", destViewController.stateName];

    _searchBar.text = @"";

    [_searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
}
```

Screenshots:

**Before search is enabled**

[image]

**After search is typed in**

[image]

**After I go back to states tableview**

[image]

As you can see, the view still looks like the search bar is enabled, with a missing keyboard.

Thanks

Comment: How are you "going back"?  What's creating that dim overlay?

Comment: It is embedded in a Navigation Controller

Comment: I asked two different questions and that doesn't actually directly answer either.

Comment: Hmm, I will post my class, I might not know how to answer it.

Comment: I have posted my class

Comment: it is like the search bar has been pressed when I go back....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you try the following in your `RootTableViewController.m` file...

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if (self.searchBar.text.length) {
         [self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:NO];
    }
}
```

(Note - it is usually necessary to call `super` for each TVC lifecycle method.)

(This life cycle method is called every time your TVC is to be presented on screen, and completes containing code *before* appearing on screen.)

As an aside, try commenting out the `resignsFirstResponder` call in your `prepareForSegue` method - I suspect it is unnecessary.

As another aside, typing the keystrokes Cmd+s, with the iOS Simulator as the current window, will create a perfectly framed screenshot, usually saved to your Desktop.

**UPDATE:**

It is important to declare the protocols you intend to follow in your class.

In this case, we need to advise use of search bar and search display controller delegate methods.

Instead of the `viewWillAppear:animated` method I suggested above (remove it), try the following...

In your `RootTableViewController.h` file replace the following line...

```
@interface RootTableViewController : UITableViewController
```

with...

```
@interface RootTableViewController : UITableViewController <UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayControllerDelegate>
```

Then in your `prepareForSegue` method, replace the following line...

```
[_searchBar resignsFirstResponder]
```

with...

```
[_searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:NO];
```

This is based on my assumption that the  instance variable `_searchDisplayController` is automatically synthesised.

Does this second suggestion help?

Comment: Thank you, I will try this as soon as I get home

Comment: should this return "self"?

Comment: @javaGeek sorry I will adjust my code to correct the return type. As far as I can recall, all TVC lifecycle methods are (void) - they do not return a value.

Comment: I tried that too.... and it didn't work... Can I put that method anywhere in the class or should it be in a specific spot?

Comment: The reason we structure code in a particular manner in Objective C is to assist with readability - both for ourselves and anyone else who may in the future need to read our code. For simplicity (there are broader considerations not relevant here) the compiler only requires that the method is placed within the `@implementation` block.

Comment: I have added my update with your method inside... It doesn't work where I have it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Give me a some time and I'll see what I can figure out.

Comment: how do i know if my "_searchDisplayController" is automatically synthesized?

Comment: It won't build because it doesn't like the "[_searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:NO];" line

Comment: I just figured out the problem, mostly because of you. You just need to add the "[self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:NO];" line in the segue

Answer (score 0):

```
_searchBar.text = @"";
```

Probably better to set it to an empty string rather than `nil`.

As for hiding the keyboard, try this:

```
[_searchBar resignFirstResponder];
```

Comment: The only problem now is that it still has the search bar highlighted with no keyboard, with the states in the background. Any suggestions?

Comment: You're going to have to provide some more context then.  Perhaps a screenshot of how it looks before you enable the search bar for the first time and what it looks like after you've enabled it, as well as any code you're using to enable/disable it.  It's a bit unclear to me what the actual problem is beyond simply hiding the keyboard (which my answer resolves).

Comment: will add screenshots ASAP

Comment: have added screen shots and more syntax